# How to open a port in Linux for other users in same network?

Tags: iptables, firewall, port

I have an application running that is listening on port 7896. I can access that using localhost and port 7896 but other users in the same network can't access that using my IP address and port 7896. I have firewall disabled.

What should I do to make that accessible for other users on the network.

Output of `netstat -lntu`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33583         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 10.42.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7896          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1720            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:14777         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:7896                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 10.42.0.1:5060          0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40172           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1900            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 10.42.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41207           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 :::35359                :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*
```

Comment: You should configure the service to listen on the desired network interface or all interfaces. Usually this is found in the applications' config file.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, configure the service to listen to address `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`. Specifying `127.0.0.1` is an explicit action required by the program listening on that port, so the service seems to be intended only for local clients, or that is just the default configuration.

If you can't configure the service to listen on `0.0.0.0`, the easiest solution is to setup a redirection with `xinetd` or `systemd`.